# Trying to write a combinations function in Python on my own, not working

Tags: python, combinations

I'm trying to solve this problem here: https://codingbat.com/prob/p252079?parent=/home/peter@norvig.com

> In math, a "combination" of a set of things is a subset of the things. We define the function combinations(things, k) to be a list of all the subsets of exactly k elements of things. Conceptually, that's all there is, but there are some questions to settle: (A) how do we represent a subset? (B) What order are the elements within each subset? (C) What order to we list the subsets? Here's what we will agree to: (A) a subset will be a list. (B) The order of elements within a list will be the same as the order within 'things'. So, for example, for combinations([1, 2, 3], 2) one of the subsets will be [1, 2]; whereas [2, 1] is not a subset. (C) The order of subsets will be lexicographical or sorted order -- that is, combinations([1, 2, 3], 2) returns [ [1, 2], [1, 3], 2, 3] ] because [1, 2] < [1, 3] < [2, 3]. You might want to use the function 'sorted' to make sure the results you return are properly ordered.
>
> combinations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2) → [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [3, 4], [3, 5], [4, 5]]
>
> combinations([1, 2, 3], 2) → [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]
>
> combinations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 5) → [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 6], [1, 2, 3, 5, 6], [1, 2, 4, 5, 6], [1, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]

Here's my code:

```
def combinations(things, k):
  if k == 0 or k == len(things):
    return [things]
  elif len(things) < k:
    return
  else:
    finalcomb = []
    subcomb1 = combinations(things[1:], k - 1)
    subcomb2 = combinations(things[1:], k)
    for i in range(len(combinations(things[1:], k - 1))):
      firstelement = [things[0]]
      firstelement += combinations(things[1:], k - 1)[i]
      finalcomb.append(firstelement)
    for j in range(len(combinations(things[1:], k))):
      finalcomb.append(combinations(things[1:], k)[j])
    return finalcomb
```

However, this is the output:
[Haven't hit 10 reputation yet so it's a link to the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsSt0.png) I'm not sure what I did wrong, can anybody help me out? Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. " Haven't hit 10 reputation yet so it's a link to the error. " In general, please avoid using images unless they are really necessary to show the problem. It appears that instead of an error message, you have graphic-formatted output (done either by a third-party library or by an environment like Jupyter) from an automated test program. You should try manually calling the function with specific inputs where you know what the output should be, show the actual vs. expected outputs, and explain - in your own words - any *pattern* you notice in the incorrect output.

Comment: It appears that generally, the problem is that the output sometimes includes extra elements that are longer than the requested length. Yes? The next step is to figure out *why*, by [carefully tracing through the logic of the code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). As an aside, [please do not use `range(len(...` like that](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this. When `k == 0` it shouldn't return `[things]`. It should return an empty array. Similar to when `len(things) < k:`. This is because, when `k == 0`, it means we that we have already found all the numbers for that specific combination.

But there's one more problem. We're returning an empty array. However, in the `for` loops, we're iterating over the returned array. So if the array is empty, nothing happens. So what we should really return is an empty 2D array. I won't go into too much detail about what the problem is since it's better for you to try and understand why it's not working. Try adding print statements inside and outside the for loops.

Anyway, the working code looks like this:

```
def combinations(things, k):
  if k == len(things):
    return [things[:]]
  if len(things) < k or k == 0:
    return [[]]
  finalcomb = []
  subcomb1 = combinations(things[1:], k - 1)
  subcomb2 = combinations(things[1:], k)
  for comb in subcomb1:
    firstelement = [things[0]]
    firstelement += comb
    finalcomb.append(firstelement)
  finalcomb += subcomb2
  return finalcomb
```

Note a few things:

- Use the variables you've already assigned (I'm assuming you forgot about them)
- Lists can be concatenated using `+`, similar to strings. If you `return` within an if statement, you don't need an `else` for the next line since if the `if` statement is satisfied, it would definitely not go to the `else`.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can try using `itertools`:

```
import itertools
output = []
for nums in itertools.combinations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2):
    output.append(list(nums))
print(output)
```

**output**:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [3, 4], [3, 5], [4, 5]]
```

For 3 nums:

```
import itertools
output = []
for nums in itertools.combinations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3):
    output.append(list(nums))
print(output)
```

**Output**:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [1, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5], [2, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]]
```